# Listbox could not resize automatically in Tkinter (python)

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I have written a Tkinter app with Python (2.7), I found that the listbox does not grow to fit the outer window when dragging in vertical direction (to increase the height of the window).

The code is as following shown

```
from Tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    mainframe = Frame(root)
    mainframe.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    status = Entry(mainframe)
    status.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES, fill=X)

    list = Listbox(mainframe)
    list.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

So what's the problem? Is there any way to resizing the listbox in vertical direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expanding the space for the Entry widget, but you only fill it to X.

If you want to keep the Entry as it is and only expand the Listbox use: `status.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=NO, fill=X)`

If you want to expand both the Listbox and the Entry use:
`status.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)`